# Mixed text-justification or tabstops in legends in R

Tags: r, legend

I want a legend like this:

[image]

I created this with five (sic!) `legend()`s, placing them side-by-side. Here is a working code sample (without colors):

```
plot(1, 0, xlim=c(1,11), ylim=c(0,45))
legend(0.6, 46.75, c("KVT", "", "", "IPT", "", ""), pch = c(0, 1, 2), bty = "n")
legend(1.4, 46.75, c(expression(paste("t1:  ", italic(M), " =")), "t3:", "t5:", "t1:", "t3:", "t5:"), bty = "n")
legend(3.35, 46.75, c(19.31, 9.91, 10.79, 19.36, 9.69, 2.82), bty = "n", adj = 1)
legend(3.6, 46.75, "n = ", bty = "n")
legend(4.7, 46.75, c(213, 208, 61, 186, 159, 11), bty = "n", adj = 1)
```

This works, as you can see, but I need to loop through several variables, with different means and scales (here: 0 to 45), and I don't want to manually adjust the placement of five legends each time.

**How can I create a similar legend using only one `legend("topleft", ...)`, employing something similar to tabstops in Word to place the text within each line, or, if that is not possible, automatically placing multiple text boxes similar to a `float: left` in CSS.**

*Note that the columns of numbers are right-justified.*

---

I tried with the `ncol` argument in `legend()`, but could get neither the partial right-alignment nor the partial suppression of symbols to work.

---

Your solution need not use the given numbers, symbols or colors. They will only make the code confusing.

Comment: You need to generate the character labels in the legend separately, which can be vectorized with liberal use of `sprintf()` and `paste()`. If you post some sample code/data people could even show you how.

Comment: @ilir I posted some sample code. I'd be grateful if you could show me how.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge there is no way to specify tab stops, but you could use space padding to control alignment. Here is the closest I could get, with 2 caveats

1. There must be some syntax to make it evaluate `italic(M)` but, for convenience, I replaced it with the letter "M"
2. I had to use fidex-width fonts to make sure the spaces align

Here is my proposed solution:

```
# store components of each row in a separate vector
l1 <- c("KVT", "", "", "IPT", "", "")
l2 <- c("t1: M =", "t3:", "t5:", "t1:", "t3:", "t5:")
l3 <- c(19.31, 9.91, 10.79, 19.36, 9.69, 2.82)
l4 <- c("n =", rep("", 5))
l5 <- c(213, 208, 61, 186, 159, 11)

# merge everything together with suitable space padding
tags <- paste(sprintf("%3s", l1),
          sprintf("%-8s", l2),
          sprintf("%5s", l3),
          sprintf("%-3s", l4),
          sprintf("%3s", l5))
plot(1, 0, xlim=c(1,11), ylim=c(0,45))

par(family="mono")  ## have to use monotype for spaces to align
legend(0.6, 46.75, tags, pch = c(0, 1, 2), bty = "n")
```

I hope that helps, even if it's not exactly what you requested.